# Wordpress - Jigoshop conditional statements

Tags: php, wordpress, product, conditional-statements, jigoshop

I'm using Jigoshop and Wordpress.

My main goal is to load a different sidebar in different product categories.

I've managed to do this by using :

```
function jigoshop_get_sidebar() {

    if(is_shop()) get_sidebar('shop'); if ( is_product_category('poura'))
        get_sidebar('cigars');
}
```

in my functions.php file.

Now the issue is that I have some products that are in not just one category, so when I try doing something like this:

```
function jigoshop_get_sidebar() {
    if(is_shop()) get_sidebar('shop'); if ( is_product_category('poura'))
           get_sidebar('cigars'); if ( is_product_category('cigarillos'))
           get_sidebar('shop');
}
```

I now get both of the sidebars ('cigars','shop') because some products share both the category 'poura' and 'cigarillos'.

How is it possible to have just one sidebar under these circumstances?

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "else if" statement is not resolving your problem?

Basically what i meant was the you need a switch case not a lot of different ifs.

```
function jigoshop_get_sidebar() { 
    if(is_shop()) 
           get_sidebar('shop');
    elseif ( is_product_category('poura'))
           get_sidebar('cigars'); 
    elseif ( is_product_category('cigarillos'))
           get_sidebar('cigarillos');
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your interest in this.

The thing is that many products are in both categories ('poura' and 'cigars'), so when I'm in the general page of cigars, just because I have products with both of the categories it loads both of the sidebars, even by using the "else if" statement. 

I know it's kinda complex, at least in my mind.

Comment: Well in your code you add the sidebar shop, than you check the category, and add the other sidebars, i edited my answer, see line 3 you add sidebar shop, than you check 'poura' and add cigars, than you check cigarillos and add shop again. Maybe i don't get your scenario :S

Comment: Yeah, and it's my fault really that you're not getting it.

I'll try to be extremely clear about it so you and other understand:

I have a product page that displays some products that are in both categories , poura and cigarillos. So that means that the same product is both categories.

That's why when I call different sidebars for the two categories it shows both of the sidebars in the same page, because each product is in both categories. 

I am trying to find a way to narrow it down with other conditional statements such as is_page or is_page_template but the last don't make in difference

Comment: Ok the product got 2 categories, but you want to show just 1 sidebar correct?

Comment: Well not even the third code that i posted works for you? That one should show just 1 sidebar, and if i understood correctly, the default sidebar should be the 'shop' one right?

Comment: It was my bas using the shop sidebar twice. 

This is the appropriate code that i have now :

function jigoshop_get_sidebar() {

 if(is_shop()) 
           get_sidebar('shop');

    else if ( is_product_category('poura'))
           get_sidebar('cigars') ;

    else if ( is_product_category('cigarillos'))
           get_sidebar('cigarillos');


}

So 3 different sidebars for shop page, 'poura' category and 'cigarillos' category

Comment: What i posted should work for your case :S are you sure you are not creating a sidebar somewhere else?

Comment: Your answer does create different sidebars just fine, but just because the products share the same category it displays both of the sidebars. 

Meh, I'll need to do more studying I guess.

Thanks so much for your time though! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you :( but that switch is able to create just 1 sidebar, because as soon as it enters 1 condition it executes it and exits. The only way to create more sidebars with that function is to execute it again, with a different condition order.

Comment: Oh no worries! I'll just have to find a way by declaring && statements so I get what i want. Thanks!